# XML namespaces default vs namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

My colleague has given each element in a payload a namespace `ns0` for best practice, and my parser stopped working.  Reading more on the topic, it seems that declaring each element the namespace is not necessary; it can be set at the root?

> When you use multiple namespaces in an XML document, you can define
> one namespace as the default namespace to create a cleaner looking
> document. The default namespace is declared in the root element and
> applies to all unqualified elements in the document. Default
> namespaces apply to elements only, not to attributes.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/managing-namespaces-in-an-xml-document

What's the correct approach?

```
<ns0:Root
    xmlns:ns0="urn:asw:erT"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:asw:erT">
    <ns0:Ticket
        xmlns:urn="urn:asw:erT" Code="TEST" Key="1">
        <ns0:client>
            <ns0:CardNumber>12345</ns0:CardNumber>
            <ns0:OpenPointsBalance>14352</ns0:OpenPointsBalance>
            <ns0:PointsEarnedValue>46</ns0:PointsEarnedValue>
            <ns0:PointsClosingBalance>14398</ns0:PointsClosingBalance>
        </ns0:client>
    </ns0:Ticket>
</ns0:Root>
```

Comment: There is no need to mushroom namespaces. It is better to declare them once at the root level

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky is therefore `xmlns:ns0="urn:asw:erT"` declaring the namespace at root correct?

Comment: Biztalk (2006-2013)added an ns0 prefix in the mapper output as standard, a bit annoying at times if you needed a more strict approach to be complaint with receiving part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the correct approach?

Neither is more correct than the other.

### XML Document 1

The XML you posted with an explicit namespace prefix for the `"urn:asw:erT"` namespace<sup>1</sup>...

```
<ns0:Root
    xmlns:ns0="urn:asw:erT"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:urn="urn:asw:erT">
  <ns0:Ticket
      xmlns:urn="urn:asw:erT" Code="TEST" Key="1">
    <ns0:client>
      <ns0:CardNumber>12345</ns0:CardNumber>
      <ns0:OpenPointsBalance>14352</ns0:OpenPointsBalance>
      <ns0:PointsEarnedValue>46</ns0:PointsEarnedValue>
      <ns0:PointsClosingBalance>14398</ns0:PointsClosingBalance>
    </ns0:client>
  </ns0:Ticket>
</ns0:Root>
```

### XML Document 2

...is fully equivalent to the following XML with a `"urn:asw:erT"` default namespace:

```
<Root xmlns="urn:asw:erT">
  <Ticket Code="TEST" Key="1">
    <client>
      <CardNumber>12345</CardNumber>
      <OpenPointsBalance>14352</OpenPointsBalance>
      <PointsEarnedValue>46</PointsEarnedValue>
      <PointsClosingBalance>14398</PointsClosingBalance>
    </client>
  </Ticket>
</Root>
```

No conformant XML processor or application should treat **XML Document 1** any differently than **XML Document 2**.

> My colleague has given each element in a payload a namespace `ns0` for best practice

It's fine to use a namespace prefix for each element, but there is no consensus that such is a "best practice".

> ...and my parser stopped working

If your parser is sensitive to the difference between **XML Document 1** and **XML Document 2**, then your parser is broken.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Note:

- The repeated declaration of `xmlns:urn="urn:asw:erT"` on `ns0:Ticket` is unnecessary but allowed.
- The unused declaration of `xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"` is also unnecessary but allowed.